# Populate dropdownlist from table with parameter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with all sorts of data (description, specifics, price, ...) stored in tab2.
In tab1 i want to be able (for an unfixed amount of lines) to first select a value from column 1, this i've got figured out, and then based on this value populate the dropdownlist on column 2. But this is the problem atm, i can't get this to work for the life of me... There's not a single option giving me this possibility to perform this on 100's of lines benath eachother.

Can someone please help me.?

Thanks in advance
Hidde

Answer (score 0):

I assumed how the data in tab2 may be structured, but it's a bit unclear.

I assumed that in column 1 there could be values that occur more than once and the different values in column 2 that are behind the value are to be part of the second drop down data list.

If you're using office 365 for the first data of your drop-down list:
`=UNIQUE(FILTER(tab2!A:A,tab2!A:A<>""))`

for data in your second drop-down list (if the first drop-down is in `A1`):
`=UNIQUE(FILTER(tab2!B:B,tab2!B:B=A1))`

For older version of Excel I have the following, which is not as neat as the solution above:

If your 1st drop-down in tab1 is in cell `A2`, type the following in `B2`:
`=IFERROR(INDEX('tab2'!B:B,MATCH(0,IF($A$2='tab2'!A:A,COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,'tab2'!B:B),""),0)),"")`
Enter as array with `ctrl + shift + enter`
Drag down the formula to get the unique values from tab2 column B that meet the chosen value in `A2`.
In you second drop-down (cell `C3` for instance) type the following in the source for your drop-down list:
`=OFFSET('tab1'!$B$2,,,COUNTA($B:$B),)`
This will result in the desired data in your drop-down, however this also shows all blanks from how far you copied down your formula in column B in your drop-down list.
Also referencing to whole columns in this examples makes it way slow, so please narrow the ranges as much as possible.

I hope somebody else can show a cleaner/faster solution, but this is something.

Comment: Hey P.b, this would be exact what i need if i weren't working on a dutch office pro 2019. The function unique ain't there yet, but you are getting my problem. is there an "older" option, which is also backwards compatible? thanks

Comment: I can't get it in a way that satisfies myself. I will update my answer with how far I got.

Comment: Hope this helps you out

Comment: Working with tables would shorten the ranges and make the formulas better readable.