Attempting to create adaptive data validation list
I am attempting to create a dependent drop-down list for an inventory, that will be adaptive as categories & lists change in the foreseeable future.
VBA is blocked, so my solution has to be done without any VBA tools. Version: Excel 365 v2404 (used company-wide).
Sheet Lists contains the lists like this:




A
B
C




1
Cherry
Apple
Bananas


2
Amarena
Gala
Cavendish


3

Fuji
Blue Java


4

Granny Smith




Note that lists may be added in the future (in column D, E, etc.), and each list of items may grow or shrink.
Sheet Item Info has a dropdown repeating through column A with the list names. The goal is that when the user changes this value, the data validation list in the adjacent cell (B2 for example) will be updated to reflect the correct list items. Below I've selected "Apple", so the cell next to it should now have the options: Gala, Fuji, Granny Smith.




A
B




1
Category
Items


2
Apple
(dynamic dropdown)



Here's a link to what this 2nd list is trying to pull from.
Column A is constructed by transposing the column headers, and is the 1st list.
my 2nd list should dynamically search the table and show the drop-down, but the titles of each column will be changing over time.

Attempts
My latest attempt has been to input the following formula into the "Data Validation List" formula field, which gave me an error and did not function (despite operating just fine within the sheet when tested).
=SORT(
    UNIQUE(
        FILTER(
            INDEX(Lists!$A$1:$Z$50,0,MATCH('Item Info'!$A2, Lists!$1:$1, 0)
            ),
            (INDEX(Lists!$A$1:$Z$50, 0, MATCH('Item Info'!$A2, Lists!$1:$1, 0)) <> "") *
            (INDEX(Lists!$A$1:$Z$50, 0, MATCH('Item Info'!$A2, Lists!$1:$1, 0)) <> 'Item Info'!$A2)
        )
    )
)

My earlier attempt consisted of a formula that was too long for inserting into the "Data Validation List" formula field. I tried splitting it up into 2 parts, and then reference the cells in the formula field, but without success:
Cell1 (F2):
=ADDRESS(
    2,
    MATCH(
        'Item Info'!$A2,
        INDIRECT("'Lists'!$A$1:" & ADDRESS(1, COUNTA(Lists!$1:$1))),
        0
    ),
    ,,
    "Lists"
)

Cell2 (G2):
=ADDRESS(
    COUNTA(INDEX(Lists!$A:$Z, 0, MATCH('Item Info'!$A2, INDEX(Lists!$A:$Z, 1, 0), 0))),
    MATCH('Item Info'!$A2, INDIRECT("'Lists'!$A$1:" & ADDRESS(1, COUNTA(Lists!$1:$1))), 0),
    ,,
    "Lists"
)

These two formulas also got me the correct range, yet my attempt to reference them in the "Data Validation List" formula field lead to an error:
=INDIRECT(F2):INDIRECT(G2)

In reply, Excel told me:

You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges), array constants, or the lambda function for data validation criteria)

However, combined the formula I attempted is 306 characters, so that it would exceed the limit (255). Any guidance on how to solve my issue would be greatly appreciated.

You need to store the spill range somewhere in your sheet (for instance Sheet2!A1) then refer to that range like =Sheets!A1# you cannot use dynamic array functions directly in your list, but indirectly it works fine and is dynamical.

How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78507575/how-to-make-dynamic-drop-down-menu/78509007 ?

@Michal would work just fine if both lists would not be changing in the future.I am trying to build framework for someone not knowledgeable about Excel to be able to continue using this sheet.  Both lists will be changing.  The first was easier as it was simply a unique and transpose unique combo to establish the hierarchy for this more troublesome list.

@P.b unless I'm misunderstanding you, That's essentially what my first list is doing - but the 2nd I don't believe can operate in the same fashion.

Apologies: didn't realize my screenshot had been removed.  Re-added.  Column A is the drop down of the 1st list, and is a unique/transpose formula of the 1st row in each column - allowing an adapting category breakdown.

You mean like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65053952/12634230

@P.b close - if it was 1 column I'd be fine, but this list needs to identify which column to pull the list from, depending on the first.   I did include a screenshot in my post;  2nd list needs to pull the list of a column ranging from B:H in the screenshot I provided, depending on the value from the 1st list (which you can see filled in Column A).  This process (of two dependent lists) will be occurring on every row of another tab.  My hope is that if this works, the category & item lists will be self-adjusting without Excel knowledge for the users.

Here's an approach without the need for (transformed) duplication of the data elsewhere in the workbook:
=OFFSET(
    INDEX(Lists!$A$1:$E$1, 1, MATCH($A2, Lists!$A$1:$E$1, 0)),
    1, 0,
    COUNTIF(
        OFFSET(
            INDEX(Lists!$A$1:$E$1, 1, MATCH($A2, Lists!$A$1:$E$1, 0)),
            1, 0, 5
        ),
        "<>" & ""
    )
)

Assuming (as an example) the following in Sheet Lists:

I.e.:

Expecting a maximum of 5 columns (in the formula adjust $E according to needs)
Expecting a maximum of 5 rows (in the formula adjust 5 (at end of OFFSET) according to needs)

For your categories in 'Item Info'!A2:A*, I've used:
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Lists!$A$1:$E$1,Lists!$A$1:$E$1<>""))

(Again: adjust $E according to needs.)
Setup

In Sheet Item Info select the entire appropriate range in Column B for actual and potential matches in column A. In my example, this would be B2:B6 (recall: we expect a maximum of 5 columns).
Go to Data -> Data Tools -> Data Validation (shortcut: Alt + A + V + V).
Select List and in the Source field enter above formula.

Here is the formula without the indentation:
=OFFSET(INDEX(Lists!$A$1:$E$1,1,MATCH($A2,Lists!$A$1:$E$1,0)),1,0,COUNTIF(OFFSET(INDEX(Lists!$A$1:$E$1,1,MATCH($A2,Lists!$A$1:$E$1,0)),1,0,10),"<>"&""))

In action:

Explanation Formula

We use MATCH to locate 'Item Info'!$A2 in the header (relative row reference to accommodate drag down).
We use the result of MATCH inside INDEX to get a Reference to use inside OFFSET. Note that we do this to avoid INDIRECT and ADDRESS. Both are so-called volatile functions, which means that they are continously recalculated every time there is a change in the workbook. That would needlessly impact performance.
For OFFSET, we now have the Reference. We add:

Rows offset: 1 (we start one row below header)
Height. We could just set this to the maximum amount of rows (i.e. 5 in our example), but that would leave a trailing blank for the dropdown. So, instead we apply COUNTIF on that maximum range and count only the cells that are non-BLANK. N.B. This means that all your entries need to be entered in consecutive rows. I.e., don't leave blanks (you could apply conditional formatting to alert users to such an error when they add entries). If you don't want to risk it, just get rid of the COUNTIF and settle for the trailing blank in the dropdown.



Prettified version with LET:
=LET(
    HEADER, Lists!$A$1:$E$1,
    IDX_CAT, MATCH($A2, HEADER, 0),
    START, INDEX(HEADER, 1, IDX_CAT),
    OFF, OFFSET(START, 1, 0, 5),
    NON_BLANKS, COUNTIF(OFF, "<>" & ""),
    OFFSET(START, 1, 0, NON_BLANKS)
)


Perfect! Thank you! Offset to provide a "max range" and then filtering out blanks is so much easier than whatever shenanigans I was attempting to do.  Thanks again.  I tried to upvote but I don't have the reputation necessary to do so.

Added an explanation on how the formula works, and why you do well to avoid INDIRECT and ADDRESS in the future. Was fun to flex my Excel muscles again. It has been a while. Also, appreciate your readiness to get your question into shape in the Staging Ground. Good luck with your project!

@ouroboros1 - what tool did you use to create the animated pic?

@Michal: neat, right? I'm by no means an expert on this and stumbled on it by accident. That's some time ago, should be: https://www.cockos.com/licecap/. Usage straightforward. I use it for this kind of thing or to get a snip from a vid to share among friends, etc. Easy tool.
